# Get Twitter Posts with Profile Images

Tags: iphone, twitter

I'm new to iPhone application development. I like to show comments which are posted in twitter with time and user profile image. I have an url to get rss feed from the twitter. I'm able to get the posts but cannot retrieve the user profile image. So anybody have an idea in this please help me to show comments with user profile image. Any suggestions are accepted. Currently, I'm using this url (http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/19496136.rss) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the better idea is to use the [Twitter Api](http://dev.twitter.com/doc) for this kind of interaction.

You can write your own "REST client" but I suggest you to do not reinvent the wheel and use the amazing [MGTwitterEnginge](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) that provide a convenient Objective-c API so you don't have to deal with the REST API directly .